# Domain wide login shell for user

Tags: windows, active-directory

It is possible to change a user's login shell to a different then explorer.exe in the user's registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`). For example we can setup it to `explore.exe -k serverfault.com` and the user can view in kiosk mode only this site.

However, this configuration is done in the user's profile and there is only on the computer where it is made (*roaming profiles unfortunately can not be used in my case*).

In the Linux world, while creating user has the ability to set login shell.

I'm looking for an opportunity to realize such in Window sdomain: set a domain user login shell in an active directory to the setting earned on all Windows computers in the domain.

Accepted any ideas. Roaming profiles are not available unfortunately.

**UPD.** I thought about setting a registry key of the user through the GPP, but:

1. I'm not sure how it works when user first log
2. After the [MS16-072](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3159398) update, there are some problems with the Group policy security filtering only to specific users.

Comment: 1. See my updated answer, it should work on the first login too.
2. I wrote in my answer to add "Domain Computers", so the filtering would work and mentioned the relevant KB number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it using a GPO.
You can set reg keys in:
GPO > User Settings > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry > New > Registry Item
Set it to Update
set the hive (HKCU)
set the Key Path (Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon)
set the Value Name (remove the V in the checkbox) to "shell"
set the value type to string, and the value data to whatever you like (e.g. iexplore.exe -k serverfault.com).

Filter the GPO so it apply only the user\group you want (don't forget to add "Domain Computers", so the policy can be applied - KB3163622).

**UPDATE**
Just found out there's an actual GP setting for this:
User Settings > Administrative Templates > System > Custom user interface
This should work just fine on the user's first login.

Comment: So how do you describe it does not work. Creating a `HKCU` key does not give any effect it if in the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\system.ini\boot\Shell` not set to `USR:Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`. By default it has `SYS:Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` value

Comment: Weird, never heard of that key, and it always worked perfectly for me.
Anyway, you can set that HKLM key on the machines you want with a GPO (preferably a separate one). AFAIR all users have "explorer" in their "shell" keys by default, so it shouldn't create any new problems.

Comment: Also, since this is a reg key, it will work only after the second login.